# drawer menu opening activities and fragments

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

Right now some of my menu items open only fragments, how do I get them to open activities as well. At the moment I'm using the NavController from Navigation Graph to open the fragments

MainActivity.java

````
   NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {


                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.menuLeave:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "adeus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.menuAccount:

                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.navHostFragment, new ContaFragment())
                                .commit();
                        break;
                    case R.id.menuPrincipal:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.navHostFragment, new PrincipalFragment())
                                .commit();
                        break;
                }

                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;

            }
        });

```
````

Comment: open Activity with Intent in case that you want to load an activity.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You should read this answer and follow those steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/67389269/12660050

**2)** Set intent to any particular menu item.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {


            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                //put your activity intent here
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DestinationActivityName.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                    break;
              }
         }
```