# Java - Click on the menu item to open fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm working on android studio to add the menu in the group using with the id. I have got a problem with the menu click event because it will not do anything when I click on it.

This is what I have tried:

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
Fragment newFragment = null; // This is the fragment you want to put into the FrameLayout
int id = item.getItemId();

```
    if (id == R.id.nav_group1) {
        newFragment = new FolderFragment();
    }

    // Let's put the new fragment into the FrameLayout
    // If you use the support action bar, use getSupportFragmentManager(), else getFragmentManager()
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, newFragment); // R.id.fragment_container = FrameLayout ID
    transaction.commit();

    return true;
}
```

Here is what I use to add the menu:

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();

try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(folders);
    int id = 1;
    int order = 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        String folder = jsonArray.getString(i);

        menu.add(R.id.nav_group1, id, order, folder)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
        id++;
            order++;
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_inbox, R.id.nav_important, R.id.nav_sent, R.id.nav_drafts, R.id.nav_spam, R.id.nav_trash, R.id.nav_group1, R.id.nav_create_new_folder, R.id.nav_contact)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

What I'm trying to achieve is when I click on the menu, I want to open the fragment under the `nav_group`.

Can you please show me an example how I could click on the menu to open the fragment when I added the menu using the java?

Comment: If you are using a `NavHostFragment`, you should never be using a `FragmentTransaction`. Have you [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake No I am not using `NavHostFragment` so how I can click on the menu item event? what event i should use to get the menu item click event to work?

Comment: It certainly looks like you are with an `R.id.nav_host_fragment` and `Navigation.findNavController` call.

Comment: @ianhanniballake yes i am using it so how I can call the fragment_mailbox when I click on the menu items?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Do you have any idea??????????????????

Comment: Follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/67389269/12660050 to solve your problem.