# My navigation drawer wont open profile fragment with (recyclerview, tablayout and viewpager inside fragment)

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview, navigation-drawer, android-tablayout

all. I'm having a problem.

I am trying to make an application, wherein a navigation-drawer is the source of navigation. In this application, I have some fragments with activities. The problem is, that if I run my profile fragment (which have uses tablayout and recyclerview) in an application for itself, it works. [The application when it runs in it's own application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx8Rm.jpg)

However, when I attempt to add it to an application, wherein it should be a fragment in a navigation drawer, the application can compile, but when I click on the menuitem in the emulator, it crashes.

I will add the code I have at the moment:

**Main Activity**

```
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.example.sustainably.ui.myprofile.MainActivityProfile;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_friends, R.id.nav_messages, R.id.nav_bookmarks, R.id.nav_myprofile, R.id.nav_discoverforums, R.id.nav_settings, R.id.nav_logout)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }


    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        // code here
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_friends:
                        // code here
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_messages:
                        // code here
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_bookmarks:
                        // code here
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_myprofile:
                        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivityProfile.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_discoverforums:
                        //code here
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_settings:
                        //code here
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_logout:
                        //code here
                        break;
                }
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
}
```

and  in the profile fragment package i have 6 java classes:

**BookmarkModel.java**

```
    private String Title;
    private int Photo;

    public BookmarkModel() {
    }

    public BookmarkModel(String title, int photo) {
        Title = title;
        Photo = photo;
    }

    // Getter
    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }
    public int getPhoto() {
        return Photo;
    }
    // Setter
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Title = title;
    }

    public void setPhoto(int photo) {
        Photo = photo;
    }
}
```

**MainActivityProfile.java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.sustainably.R;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class MainActivityProfile extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_myprofile);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout_id);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_id);
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Add Fragment Here

        adapter.AddFragment(new PublicBookmarkFragment(), "Public Bookmarks");
        adapter.AddFragment(new LatestPostsFragment(), "Latest Posts");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_outline_bookmarks_24);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_outline_textsms_24);
    }
}
```

**PublicBookmarkFragment**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.sustainably.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PublicBookmarkFragment extends Fragment {

    View v;
    private RecyclerView myrecyclerview;
    private List<BookmarkModel> lstBookmarkModel;

    public PublicBookmarkFragment() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.public_bookmarks_fragment, container, false);
        myrecyclerview = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.bookmarks_recyclerview);
        RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), lstBookmarkModel);
        myrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2));
        myrecyclerview.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        lstBookmarkModel = new ArrayList<>();
        lstBookmarkModel.add(new BookmarkModel("Salad", R.drawable.annapelzer));
        lstBookmarkModel.add(new BookmarkModel("Pasta", R.drawable.brookelark_1));
        lstBookmarkModel.add(new BookmarkModel("Fruit Salad", R.drawable.brookelark_2));
        lstBookmarkModel.add(new BookmarkModel("Smoothies with fruit", R.drawable.brookelark_3));
        lstBookmarkModel.add(new BookmarkModel("Soup", R.drawable.cala));
        lstBookmarkModel.add(new BookmarkModel("Lobster Salad", R.drawable.davide_cantelli));
        lstBookmarkModel.add(new BookmarkModel("Breakfast Toast with Berries", R.drawable.joseph_gonzales));

    }
}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.sustainably.R;

import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context mContext;
    List<BookmarkModel> mData;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<BookmarkModel> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v;
        v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_bookmarks, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder vHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);

        return vHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.tv_title.setText(mData.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.img.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getPhoto());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView tv_title;
        private ImageView img;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tv_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_bookmarks);
            img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_bookmarks);

        }
    }
}
```

**ViewPagerAdapter**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ViewPagerAdapter  extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    private final List<Fragment> lstFragment = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> lstTitles = new ArrayList<>();


    public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return lstFragment.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lstTitles.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return lstTitles.get(position);
    }

    public void AddFragment (Fragment fragment, String title) {

        lstFragment.add(fragment);
        lstTitles.add(title);

    }
}
```

**fragment_myprofile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myprofile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/profile_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/TabContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIconTint="@color/dark_green"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/dark_green"
            app:tabInlineLabel="true"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabRippleColor="@color/light_green"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/dark_green"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"></com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>


        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_id"></androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**public_bookmarks_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bookmarks_recyclerview">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**item_bookmarks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_bookmarks"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_bookmarks"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_green"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I'm new at asking questions in here, so if I missed some information you need, or messed something up, please tell me what you need, and I will provide that aswell. Hope you can help.

For clarification as requested:
**Logcat errormessages when I click on the menu**

```
2021-05-06 15:28:54.971 18053-18053/com.example.sustainably E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sustainably, PID: 18053
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.sustainably.ui.myprofile.MainActivityProfile cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:548)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:390)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.instantiateFragment(FragmentNavigator.java:132)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:162)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:58)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1066)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:944)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:877)
        at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(NavigationUI.java:97)
        at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI$3.onNavigationItemSelected(NavigationUI.java:453)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:217)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:834)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:985)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:416)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

**mobile_navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.example.sustainably.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_friends"
        android:name="com.example.sustainably.ui.friends.FriendsFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_friends"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_friends" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_bookmarks"
        android:name="com.example.sustainably.ui.bookmarks.BookmarksFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_bookmarks"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_bookmarks" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_myprofile"
        android:name="com.example.sustainably.ui.myprofile.profileRecycle.MyProfileFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_myprofile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_myprofile" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_discoverforums"
        android:name="com.example.sustainably.ui.discoverforums.DiscoverForumsFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_discoverforums"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_discoverforums" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_messages"
        android:name="com.example.sustainably.ui.messages.MessagesFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_messages"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_messages" />
</navigation>
```

The code in it's entirety: https://github.com/CabCabz/SustainablyProblem.git

Comment: Can you provide error message(Run or Logcat) to know exactly.

Comment: @VatsalDholakiya I edited my question, and attached the error messages from logcat in the bottom. Hope this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

**suggestion:**

I analyzed your code, you should not used default navigation drawer setup with **mobile_navigation.xml**.

Setup drawer menu without mobile_navigation.xml: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67389269/12660050

**Solution:**

**1)** As you are using default drawer with **mobile_navigation.xml** you do not need to
use **onNavigationItemSelected()** method. So, before doing anything remove it from
your **Main Activity**.

**2)** Go to the **mobile_navigation.xml** file and change tag name **fragment** to **activity** in which you are using as a **MainActivityProfile.java**.

**Before:**

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_myprofile"
    android:name="com.example.sustainably.ui.myprofile.profileRecycle.MyProfileFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_myprofile"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_myprofile" />
```

**After:**

```
 <activity
    android:id="@+id/nav_myprofile"
    android:name="com.example.sustainably.ui.myprofile.profileRecycle.MyProfileFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_myprofile"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_myprofile" />
```

By changing only this you can solve your problem!!

Comment: Should I change from default navigation to the one you linked to (Stackoverflow one)?

Because I have now removed the onNavigationItemSelected() and changed from fragment to activity, yet it still crashes when I click the menu item. The logcat errorcode still say MainActivityProfile cannot be case to androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

Comment: Yes, it's best way to use navigation drawer.

Comment: If possible then put your mobile_navigation.xml file in this post.

Comment: I edited my MainActivity to with the suggestions from the link. Whereas the application now doesn't crash, it does not open anything when I click the menu-item either. I really appreciate the help by the way. I've been struggling with this for ages. Am I missing something in the onNavigationItemSelected?

Comment: Make sure you have written  "return true; " by the end of onNavigationItemSelected. Also in switch case condition you should write default: case .

Comment: I have. It seems that the problem now, that I have used MainActivityProfile as kind of a fragment, however it extends AppCompatActivity instead of fragment. This worked in my other application, but for some reason not in this.

In onNavigationItemSelected i wrote:
case R.id.nav_myprofile:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,
                                new MainActivityProfile()).commit();
                        drawer.closeDrawers();
                        break;
But it says i provided activity instead of fragment

Comment: I have attached the mobile_navigation.xml that I deleted  in the bottom of the initial post.

Comment: You haven't changed your <fragment> to <activity> yet in mobile_navigation.xml. I edited my post please copy and paste this code in your mobile_navigation.xml.

Comment: I deleted my mobile_navigation.xml as per the link, and implemented the suggested steps (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67386965/android-navigation-drawer-fragments-overlapping-with-dynamic-meny-items/67389269#67389269) instead of using the mobile_navigation.xml. So I can't change the tag from fragment to activity. The mobile_navigation.xml i posted in the initial question is how it looked before I deleted it.

Comment: I honestly appreciate the help, but it seems difficult to explain it completely or correctly in short messages. I have uploaded the file to a Github repository. It may be easier to see the problem this way. If it's too much to ask for, I understand. 
https://github.com/CabCabz/SustainablyProblem.git - The link to the problem

Comment: In onNavigationItemSelected write: 
R.id.nav_myprofile:  
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivityProfile.class);
startActivity(intent); 
drawer.closeDrawers();
 break;

Comment: It can compiles, but still crash when I click the menuItem.

Comment: You haven't registered your "MainActivityProfile" in AndroidManifest.xml.
Add below code in your <application> tag in  AndroidManifest.xml file.





 <activity
            android:name=".ui.myprofile.MainActivityProfile"
            android:label="MainActivityProfile"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sustainably.NoActionBar" />

Comment: It worked! It opens up correctly! Now, however, the navigation-menu icon/toolbar dissappears once I get to the MainActivityProfile menuitem? Thank you for the help so far nonetheless! Reaclly appreciated

Comment: Yes, it will disappear, because you are opening new activity not a fragment.

Comment: To attach the toolbar to this new activity, I will have to create it in that activity and call upon it aswell, right? Optimally, I would like for the toolbar to be there at all time.

Comment: So, overall to keep the same toolbar and drawer menu you should use fragment instead of activity for the profile view.

Comment: I know I'm being a pain i nthe ass, but that was what I was trying to do. But for some reason, it would not let me. Apparently I was using making an activity, and not a fragment, but I'm not sure how to fix that. Thank you for the help though!