# Opening a fragment which replaces nav_host with being able to go back

Tags: java, android, fragment, native, android-bottomnavigationview

I am trying to show a new fragment where the nav_host_fragment is but I want the old one to show whenever I click on backButton or on an X in my app (I added that already).
In the state that it is in right now it won't let me get out of the PlaylistFragment.

I also tried around with FragmentTransaction.add(...) but I couldn't figure how I get this working

My Code:

MainActivity.java:

```
 Fragment fragment = new PlayListFragment(position);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment oldFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragment.getClass().getName());

        //if oldFragment already exits in fragmentManager use it
        if (oldFragment != null) {
            //fragment = oldFragment;
        }

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment, fragment.getClass().getName());

        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);

        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("playlist");

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

PlaylistFragment.java:

```
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack("playlist", 0);
```

EDIT:
When I tried putting null instead of "playlist" in the backstack:
Yup. Then I see both fragments overflowing each other:
Normal state:
https://prnt.sc/12yitg5

When clicking on the "downloaded songs":
https://prnt.sc/12yiu79

When clicking back in the fragment:
https://prnt.sc/12yiuy6

EDIT: When I click on the X again it shows me the home fragment while bottom nav highlights the Library tab.

Comment: Tried to to put fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); instead of fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("playlist"); ?

Comment: Yup. Then I see both fragments overflowing each other:
Normal state:
https://prnt.sc/12yitg5

When clicking on the "downloaded songs":
https://prnt.sc/12yiu79

When clicking back in the fragment:
https://prnt.sc/12yiuy6

EDIT: When I click on the X again it shows me the home fragment while bottom nav highlights the Library tab.

Comment: Visit this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67389269/12660050 only thing is you need to apply according to your code.

Comment: It worked. Thanks for finding this. Somehow I didn't.

Comment: If you are using a `NavHostFragment`, you should *never* have to write a `FragmentTransaction` ever. You would [navigate to a new screen](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#navigate). Why are you trying to use a `FragmentTransaction` at all?

Comment: Because I want to react to a onItemClick in a listview. How else could I show him new data, without a fragment?