# fragments overlaid in bottom navigation and drawer layout using viewpager 2 in android app

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm almost new to programming in Android and there are still things that I don't handle very well. Now I'm doing a project in Android using java that has me half frustrated since I've been trying to find and fix a problem for WEEKS but I still can't identify what it is. The app consists of a view that contains a drawer layout with a series of "options", it also contains a viewpager2 and a bottom navigation with 2 other "options." The error appears when I press the bottom navigation tabs since the two fragments they overlap each other, the same happens when I select an option from the navigation drawer, the fragments are superimposed, then I leave you part of my code so that I hope you can help me, thank you very much for taking the time to help me.

main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    //variables para cargar el fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    String personName;
    ViewPager2 viewPager2;
    BottomNavigationView  bottomNavigationView;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);//se pasa el toolbar
        drawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        navigationView=findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        actionBarDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.open,R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        initView();


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.user){
            FragmentManager fragmentManager;
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
            fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new perfil_user());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
        else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.exit){
            finish();

        }
        //aquí van las otros fragment
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return false;
    }
    private void initView() {
        viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.vp_horizontal_ntb);
        viewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(100);
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);
        viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);

       bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
               Fragment fragment=null;
               switch (item.getItemId()){
                   case R.id.perfil:
                       fragment=new perfil_user();
                       break;
                   case R.id.generar_debate:
                       fragment=new genera_debate();
                       break;

               }

               if (fragment != null) {
                   FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                   transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
                   transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                   transaction.commit();
               }
               return true;
           }

       });
    }
}
```

files xml:

content main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

drawer toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#067B30"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"/>
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/vp_horizontal_ntb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

activity main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/drawer_toolbar"
        >

    </include>
    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        >

    </include>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>



</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share screenshots of expected design and your current design

Comment: Try to add fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); to your navigation drawer item selected listener and look at here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67389269/12660050

Note: You may need to return true in onNavigationItemSelected().

Comment: @Vatsal Dholakiya if I did the addToBackStack (null) thing; but even so the fragments of the navigation drawer are superimposed, with respect to return true if it does it in the code that I added

Comment: @Android Geek no friend, unfortunately I don't know why stackoverflow won't let me upload photos

Comment: Does anyone know if there is any way to leave the container fragment blank once the transition between fragments is done?

Comment: Yes, I think "transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, null);" may help to leave the container fragment blank.

Comment: I tried to remove the initview method which is related to the bottom navigation and by doing so the navigation drawer works smoothly, nothing overlaps, hopefully someone can help me integrate both components without giving me any problems.

Comment: could you help here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71800232/why-drawerlayout-3d-animation-doesnt-load